# How do you split reading a large csv file into evenly-sized chunks in Python?

Tags: python, list, csv, chunks

In a basic I had the next process.

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('huge_file.csv', 'rb'))

for line in reader:
    process_line(line)
```

See this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python). I want to send the process line every 100 rows, to implement batch sharding.

The problem about implementing the related answer is that csv object is unsubscriptable and can not use len.

```
>>> import csv
>>> reader = csv.reader(open('dataimport/tests/financial_sample.csv', 'rb'))
>>> len(reader)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type '_csv.reader' has no len()
>>> reader[10:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is unsubscriptable
>>> reader[10]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is unsubscriptable
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you please answer this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/73414323/19168443?sem=2

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just make your `reader` subscriptable by wrapping it into a `list`. Obviously this will break on really large files (see alternatives in the *Updates* below):

```
>>> reader = csv.reader(open('big.csv', 'rb'))
>>> lines = list(reader)
>>> print lines[:100]
...
```

Further reading: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

---

**Update 1** (list version): Another possible way would just process each chuck, as it arrives while iterating over the lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('4956984.csv', 'rb'))

chunk, chunksize = [], 100

def process_chunk(chuck):
    print len(chuck)
    # do something useful ...

for i, line in enumerate(reader):
    if (i % chunksize == 0 and i > 0):
        process_chunk(chunk)
        del chunk[:]  # or: chunk = []
    chunk.append(line)

# process the remainder
process_chunk(chunk)
```

---

**Update 2** (generator version): I haven't benchmarked it, but maybe you can increase performance by using a chunk *generator*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('4956984.csv', 'rb'))

def gen_chunks(reader, chunksize=100):
    """ 
    Chunk generator. Take a CSV `reader` and yield
    `chunksize` sized slices. 
    """
    chunk = []
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        if (i % chunksize == 0 and i > 0):
            yield chunk
            del chunk[:]  # or: chunk = []
        chunk.append(line)
    yield chunk

for chunk in gen_chunks(reader):
    print chunk # process chunk

# test gen_chunk on some dummy sequence:
for chunk in gen_chunks(range(10), chunksize=3):
    print chunk # process chunk

# => yields
# [0, 1, 2]
# [3, 4, 5]
# [6, 7, 8]
# [9]
```

There is a minor gotcha, as [@totalhack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10682164/totalhack) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956984/how-do-you-split-reading-a-large-csv-file-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python/4957046?noredirect=1#comment103177531_4957046):

> Be aware that this yields the same object over and over with different contents. This works fine if you plan on doing everything you need to with the chunk between each iteration.

Comment: The problem is that subscribing the file, force to read all the lines of the file. This is a really huge file and memory usage raise to much if I do that.

Comment: @Mario: Added a generator version, which might be faster (but I didn't  have time to test it - maybe you do).

Comment: It's correct the second argument on enumerate() "takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)" ?

Comment: for gen_chunks(range(10), chunksize=2) → I get [[],[1],[3],[5],[7],[9]] may something be wrong?

Comment: You'll need 2.6 or higher for the `start` parameter (http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: @Mario: Ok, corrected my answer, should work now, even on earlier python versions (got rid of the `start` parameter on `enumerate`).

Comment: Thanks, however I am getting this → [0, 1, 2] [4, 5] [7, 8], could it be related also with python2.5?

Comment: @Mario: See my current answer, it should be correct and work with python 2.2 onwards.

Comment: @Mario: Wah, that's irritating. Here is another gist (https://gist.github.com/820490), just tried it myself with python 2.5. If that doesn't solve it, I'm out of options (and time ;) for this answer. Good luck!

Comment: @TheMYYN :-) Thanks any way, it's a great solution it just need more work, I would keep testing and post it complete  :)

Comment: Good answer but I found it twice as fast to split the file in linux using the split command, and then read in each chunk

Comment: **Minor gotcha**: be aware that this yields the same object over and over with different contents. This works fine if you plan on doing everything you need to with the chunk between each iteration. That's likely the intent in most cases, but if that behavior doesn't work for your situation, one option is to change `del chunk[:]` to `chunk = []`.

Comment: @totalhack I used the above code logic, but some rows get duplicated, even though there is no duplicate in the file, how can I avoid this issue?

Comment: @totalhack I used chunk =[]

Answer (score 7):

We can use pandas module to handle these big csv files.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
temp = pd.read_csv('BIG_File.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
df = pd.concat(temp, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a *good* way to do this for all `.csv` files.  You should be able to divide the file into chunks using [`file.seek`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) to skip a section of the file.  Then you have to scan one byte at a time to find the end of the row.  The you can process the two chunks independently.  Something like the following (untested) code should get you started.

```
file_one = open('foo.csv')
file_two = open('foo.csv') 
file_two.seek(0, 2)     # seek to the end of the file
sz = file_two.tell()    # fetch the offset
file_two.seek(sz / 2)   # seek back to the middle
chr = ''
while chr != '\n':
    chr = file_two.read(1)
# file_two is now positioned at the start of a record
segment_one = csv.reader(file_one)
segment_two = csv.reader(file_two)
```

I'm not sure how you can tell that you have finished traversing `segment_one`.  If you have a column in the CSV that is a row id, then you can stop processing `segment_one` when you encounter the row id from the first row in `segment_two`.