# Mongod proccess uses a lot of memory after bulk upsert with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, ram, upsert

I want to upsert records from a large csv.gzip file.
I am using generator of chunks, described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4957046/5856795) response:

```
def gen_chunks(reader, chunksize=100):
    """ 
    Chunk generator. Take a CSV `reader` and yield
    `chunksize` sized slices. 
    """
    chunk = []
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        if (i % chunksize == 0 and i > 0):
            yield chunk
            del chunk[:]
        chunk.append(line)
    yield chunk
```

I run a daemon Mongod by the following command:

```
$ mongod --dbpath data\db
```

And then start python script with using pymongo:

```
with gzip.open(filepath, 'rt', newline='') as gzip_file:
    dr = csv.DictReader(gzip_file)  # comma is default delimiter
    chunksize = 10 ** 3

    for chunk in gen_chunks(dr, chunksize):
        bulk = locations.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()
        for row in chunk:
            cell = {
                'mcc': int(row['mcc']),
                'mnc': int(row['net']),
                'lac': int(row['area']),
                'cell': int(row['cell'])
            }
            location = {
                'lat': float(row['lat']),
                'lon': float(row['lon'])
            }
            bulk.find(cell).upsert().update({'$set': {'OpenCellID': location}})
        result = bulk.execute()
```

Then the RAM memory used by a process increases (sorry for my native language on a screenshot, RAM is the third column):
[image: RAM]
After the complete execution of the script (upserting about 30 million documents), memory used by mongod reached about 15 GB!

**What am I doing wrong/misundersting?**

P.S. After restarting the daemon RAM memory is reduced to the normal (about 30 Mb).

Comment: what version of mongodb/pymongo are you running?

Comment: @steve-rossiter pymongo version is '3.3.1', mongodb, mongodb is 'v3.2.10'

Comment: do you need to use `initialize_ordered_bulk_op`? can you get away with `initialize_unordered_bulk_op` and does that help?

Comment: @SteveRossiter I will check it. But according to the logic of my program, I need just ordered upseting

Comment: @SteveRossiter same, RAM of mongod process increasing

Comment: very odd. have you specified an index anywhere? Also have you tired passing `bypass_document_validation=True`?

Comment: @SteveRossiter yes, I have compound index:  `locations.create_index([('mcc', ASCENDING),
                                ('mnc', ASCENDING),
                                ('lac', ASCENDING),
                                ('cell', ASCENDING)])`

Comment: @SteveRossiter I don't use `bypass_document_validation`, what is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130019/discussion-between-steve-rossiter-and-andrei).